# Construct a continuous function $f$ with $0\leq f\leq 1$ such that $\int_a^bf d\alpha\geq\alpha(d)-\alpha(c)-\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose that $\alpha$ is right continuous and increasing. Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $[c,d]\subset[a,b]$, construct a continuous function $f$ with $0\leq f\leq 1$ such that $\int_a^bf d\alpha\geq\alpha(d)-\alpha(c)-\epsilon$. The hint given is $f$ should "look like" the indicator function on the interval $[c,d]$

My idea was to create a function $f$, which is 0 on the interval $[a,c-\delta)$, and $(b+\delta,d]$. Then on interval $[c-\delta,d+\delta]$, we can then have something like a trapezoid, with the top reach the value $1$. Therefore, the function would be continuous. Also, the value of the integral would just be $\int_a^bf d\alpha = \int_{c-\delta}^{d+\delta}f d\alpha \geq\int_c^d 1 d\alpha $. Since $\alpha$ right continuous and increasing, $\int_c^d 1 d\alpha $ would just be $\alpha(d)-\alpha(c)$. So we have the desired result.

Is this right? I never used the information about $\epsilon$ though.

Comment: If $f = 1$, then $\int_a^b fd\alpha = \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \ge \alpha(d) - \alpha(c)\ge \alpha(d) - \alpha(c) - \epsilon$.

Comment: @JohnMa good point, I think the problem statement has the $\geq$ sign. Probably it should be another way around.

Comment: I can think of a question like: For all $\epsilon >0$, Construct a continuous $f$ on $[a,b]$ so that $0\le f\le 1$, $f  =0$ outside $[c,d]$ and $\int_a^b fd\alpha \ge \alpha(d) - \alpha(c) - \epsilon$. But for now your question seems to be trivial.